# JNI error : A class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: java

I have a MyFirstProgram.java file that contains two classes. I just modified the Path and tried to test the file with `java` and`javac`.

```
public class MyFirstProgram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello ! World :)");
    }
}
```

However, it returns me:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>java MyFirstProgram.java
Error: Could not find or load main class MyFirstProgram.java

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>javac MyFirstProgram.java
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here is the Path:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

It only works when I call javac directly in the folder:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\javac" MyFirstProgram.java

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>java MyFirstProgram
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MyFirstProgram has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Yet it can't display the message `java` and reveals there is an `UnsupportedClassVersionError`. I understand from other posts it is my Java Runtime Environnment for `javac` that might not be in accordance to the `java` command. What steps to follow so that I can print the Hello World message ?

Comment: You have both `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin` on the path. I'm guessing one of these is incorrect. What is the value of `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: @JornVernee Thanks for your comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the problem is that you're compiling with `javac` from JDK 11, and then trying to run with Java 8. Since the java.exe from `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is being picked up before `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin`. And, I'm guessing it can't find `javac` because you added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin` to the path, without restarting your shell, which means the path is not reloaded.

To resolve this you should remove the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin` entry from the path, and then update the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2` instead. Then restart your shell and it should pick up `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin` expanded from `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Comment: Thanks ! I don't have to call for `C://...` anymore and I can now call for `javac MyFirstProgram.java`. Yet when I try to call it with `java` I still have the JNI error. By the way, I'm on Windows 10 for restarting the shell I closed and reopen the terminal I was using

Comment: @ThePassenger Are you using Powershell or cmd? What happens when you type `where.exe java` ?

Comment: I'm using `cmd`, I don't know if it is a good idea as I've heard that it will be replaced by Powershell. When I do `where.exe` I get: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe`

Comment: @ThePassenger Looks like you still have the jre8 java.exe on your path. It's probably the very first path entry that you have to remove. IIRC something very similar to that first path returned by `where`.

Comment: Ok I removed `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` which was the first path entry. Reopened a terminal and it worked. Thank you for your time and patience !

Answer (score 0):

The error explains that your class is compiled by a more recent version of `JDK-11.0.2` and it executes by the lower version of `JDK-8`.

The same problem happens with me and in my case, I download [Java Uninstall tools](https://www.java.com/en/download/uninstalltool.jsp)

> This tool will check for Java versions on your computer. If
> out-of-date versions are found, this tool will help you remove them.

Actually, whatever way I downloaded the Java update of version 8 so that problem happens but With the help of this tool I easily uninstall that update of version-8 and after that run my program as usual.

In **Environment Variables** I set the ***System Variables/path*** like this which is already perfect:

Add New Variable like:

> **Variablename: JAVA_HOME**

> **Variablevalue: C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-13.0.2**

Edit the path like:

> **%JAVA_HOME%\bin**

Answer (score 0):

The error explains that your class is compiled by a more recent version of JDK-11.0.2 and it executes by the lower version of JDK-8.

In **Environment Variables** Edit **Path** listed in **System Variables**. move down the JavaPath to the bottom. Now restart the shell/cmd prompt